# Не могу выполнить POST запрос Python requests

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'X-API-Key': 'yCDUucvtMxNNIoFaFLmXFfdFyEwBrhztBEGGSN', 'X-Client-ID': 'taxi/park/94a354d1dff2471ebef68b42cd92c136'} 

print(requests.post('https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/orders/list', data=json.dumps(headers)).text)
print(requests.post('https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/orders/list', data=headers).text)
print(requests.post('https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/orders/list', headers=headers).text)
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
>>{"message":"query must be present"}
>>{"message":"request must be in json format"}
>>{"message":"request must be in json format"}
```

А вод такой же код из документации работает

```
pload = {'username':'Olivia','password':'123'}
print(requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post',data = pload).text)
```

Comment: headers - это только заголовок запроса, а нужно передавать еще тело запроса, смотрите описание и пример в документации: https://fleet.taxi.yandex.ru/docs/api/reference/Orders/v1_parks_orders_list_post.html

Answer (score 2):

Вроде в [документации](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) написано, что (для вашего кода) вызывать надо так:

```
requests.post(link, data = headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь передавать одни только заголовки, а требуются ещё и собственно данные. У меня получилось [примеры из документации](https://fleet.taxi.yandex.ru/docs/api/reference/Orders/v1_parks_orders_list_post.html) запустить так:

```
url = 'https://fleet-api.taxi.yandex.net/v1/parks/orders/list'

print(requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data)).text)
```

Но не хватает разрешения у вашего ключа API, чтобы получить результат:

```
{"message":"api key does not have sufficient permissions"}
```

Пример данных для запроса:

```
data = {
  "limit": 100,
  "query": {
    "park": {
      "car": {
        "id": "5011ade6ba054dfdb7143c8cc9460dbc"
      },
      "driver_profile": {
        "id": "33de650c6a1a40bfa78dd981817da866"
      },
      "id": "ee6f33c4562b4e1f8646d157bd70b2c4",
      "order": {
        "booked_at": {
          "from": "2019-08-08T11:58:01+03:00",
          "to": "2019-08-08T11:58:01+03:00"
        },
        "categories": "econom",
        "ended_at": {
          "from": "2019-08-08T11:58:01+03:00",
          "to": "2019-08-08T11:58:01+03:00"
        },
        "ids": "c8d40acf182b4b32af72f6ad2029031b",
        "payment_methods": "card",
        "price": {
          "from": "12345.1434",
          "to": "12345.1434"
        },
        "providers": "platform",
        "short_ids": 248,
        "statuses": "complete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее! Я думал об Этих data Но я не знаю где Эти значения брать "driver_profile": {
        "id": "33de650c6a1a40bfa78dd981817da866"

Comment: Вот. Например я хочу получить все профиля водитедей. Но там в data где мне первоначально эту инфу брать?
data = {
  "limit": 100,
  "query": {
    "park": {
      "car": {
        "id": "5011ade6ba054dfdb7143c8cc9460dbc"
      },
      "driver_profile": {
        "id": "33de650c6a1a40bfa78dd981817da866"
      },
      "id": "ee6f33c4562b4e1f8646d157bd70b2c4",

Comment: Там вроде таких данных не нужно: https://fleet.taxi.yandex.ru/docs/api/reference/DriverProfiles/v1_parks_driver-profiles_list_post.html

Comment: Так с телом разобрался вроде. Теперь пишет. 
{"message":"invalid client id or api key"}
 А как у Вас получилось по этим ключам что то получить?

Comment: Может там поняли, что толпа народа по этим ключам ломится и ключ сменили? ))